# Compiler confuses name of an (unrelated) template with method name

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

I have a compile error in the following code. It seems that the compiler interprets class method `set` as a template which - at first glance - is completely unrelated to my code.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ReduceScalar{

    public:
        T get() { return *r; };
        void set(T t) { *r = t; };
        void set(T* t) { r = t; };

    private:
        T* r;

};

template <class T>
class ReduceSum : public ReduceScalar<T>
{
    public:
        ReduceSum(T* target) { set(target); set(0); } // COMPILE ERROR


};
```

Compiler gives the following error:

```
../test/../io/scalarreducers.h:34:26: error: use of class template 'set' requires template arguments
                ReduceSum(T* target) { set(target); set(0); }
```

But I think it's because it thinks that `set` is a template:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tree:685:71: note: template is declared here
        template <class, class, class> friend class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY set;
```

I do not understand why the compiler tries to instantiate that template for method `set` and not just call method `set`. How can I resolve this name confusion?

Comment: Sure you don't have an unwanted `using namespace std;` somewhere this code is included?

Comment: Try `this->set(target);`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, that's the case. I did an edit. But what is this `set` and why is it preferred against the class method?

Comment: @Michael See here please: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I know `std::set` but what exactly is the rule to tell whether `set` is interpreted as `this->set` or `std::set` in my case?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This code is wrong even without `using namespace std;`. The base class is dependent, so it's not searched unless you do `this->set`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, that's not a duplicate. Sure the OP shouldn't be using namespace std, but that alone won't solve the problem. He'll run into additional errors once he fixes that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use variable of parent class that is template class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171242/why-cant-i-use-variable-of-parent-class-that-is-template-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will still have problems even if you get rid of that nasty `using namespace std`. The problem is that member function `set` may not exist in all instantiations. The code in the question uses `set` as an unqualified, non-dependent name. This means two things:

- The compiler will try to resolve `set` at the point where the template is defined.
- The compiler will not look into the base class `ReduceScalar<T>` for member function `set`. It can't because that member might not exist for all instantiations.

End result: The code doesn't compile. The solution is to turn that non-dependent name into a dependent name. This defers resolution of dependent names until the template instantiation. One way to do this is to explicitly use `this` (which is a dependent name).

```
template <class T>
class ReduceSum : public ReduceScalar<T>
{
public:
    ReduceSum(T* target) { this->set(target); }
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the using declaration (very different from the using directive):

```
template <class T>
class ReduceSum : public ReduceScalar<T>
{
public:
    using ReduceScalar<T>::set;
    ReduceSum(T* target) { set(target); }
};
```