# CRTP and default assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, crtp

In the following :

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base:
{
    inline Derived& operator=(const Base<Derived>& x);
}
```

Does this declaration erases the default copy assignment operator or do I have two operators :

```
inline Derived& operator=(const Base<Derived>& x); 
// (declared by me)
```

AND

```
inline Base<Derived>& operator=(const Base<Derived>& x); 
// (declared by the compiler)
```

In this case, when I call the function, how the compiler will get the right operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare *any* method that can pass for an assignment operator:

```
XXX Foo::operator=(Foo&);
XXX Foo::operator=(Foo const&);
XXX Foo::operator=(Foo volatile&);
XXX Foo::operator=(Foo const volatile&);
```

then the compiler will not generate the default version `Foo& operator=(Foo const&);`.

Note that the return type is completely free, as for other methods. You could use `void`, `bool`, whatever really. It is just *idiomatic* (but not required) to return a reference to self in order to allow *assignment chaining*: `a = b = c = 0;` which itself stems from the guideline that overloaded operators should follow the semantics of their built-in counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried? Overloading by return type only would be a compile error, so my guess is that the one defined replaces the default one.

Comment: It would be a compiler error only if the template was actually instantiated in the code. Otherwise, it will compiler just fine.

Comment: @icepack that is true, im assuming the template is instantiated

Comment: @icepack this is not true. if a template is always illformed regardless of what template parameters you pass, then a template can be rejected without instantiation too. this applies to his class template then, if the default assignment operator would be instantiated too.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Good point. However, this is compiler-specific, isn't it? The fact that the compiler can do this, doesn't mean it will. As far as the generated binary code concerned, it's fine.

Comment: @icepack right. it's basically no more than undefined behavior then. I.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589766/why-doesnt-this-code-generate-compilation-errors

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : are you ok with the validated answer or do you think that the provided code has an undefined behaviour ?