# Does static_assert require use of template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to disallow references with a class I've got and I'm seeing some strange behavior. I've built a toy example that shows what's happening.  If I have this:

```
template <class T>
struct something {
};

template <class T>
struct something<T&> {
    static_assert(false, "reference disallowed with something");
};


int main() {
    something<int>  a; (void)a;
}
```

Even though I'm not declaring an instance of something with a reference, it still fails:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 foo.cc -o foo
foo.cc:7:5: error: static assertion failed: reference disallowed with something
     static_assert(false, "reference disallowed with something");
     ^
```

If I tweak it so that it has to use the template parameter through a proxy class, then it works:

```
template <class T>
struct something {
};

template <class T>
struct something<T&> {
    template <class TT> struct falsity {
        static const bool value = false;
    };
    static_assert(falsity<T>::value, "reference disallowed with something");
};

int main() {
    something<int>  a; (void)a;
}
```

Then it works just fine, is this the expected behavior?  I would have thought the the static assert would be a member of the class regardless.

Edit: this is gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: In short: No! Try `static_assert(false, "This is false.");`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I'm not sure I understand, you don't think this is expected behavior?  Where should I try your assert?

Comment: _"Where should I try your assert?"_ Elsewhere. Point is: **It doesn't require use of template parameters.**

Comment: You could always just do `static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>…` (or `is_lvalue_reference` if that's the only kind you're after). Either way, no specialization required.

Comment: @chris I'm _actually_ trying to disallow rvalue references in a class.  So I can't use is_reference for this, I abbreviated everything a level for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Ok then, `std::is_rvalue_reference`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `static_assert` does not depend on any template parameters and so the compiler does not have to wait until instantiation of the class template to evaluate the statement. Instead it does so during the first phase of [two phase name lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) and your code fails to compile.

In your case you can fix the failure by changing the assertion to

```
static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, "reference disallowed with something");
```

Comment: Ah OK makes perfect sense, sounds like the answer is _yes_ you do need to use the template parameter or you'll basically throw the assertion regardless of instantiating the class.

Comment: @gct Right, by making the condition dependent on a template parameter, the compiler must wait until instantiation of the template to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Took me a while to dig the quote from the standard: 14.6/8 *If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.* This is the case in the question, since the `static_assert` is not dependent on the template arguments, there cannot be any *valid specialization* generated from that definition.

Comment: @David Interesting, so the assertion failure is not actually required in this case. But gcc, clang and VS2013 all fail the `static_assert` anyway, which is probably a good thing.

Comment: *no diagnostic required* does not mean that the code is correct, just that the compiler is not obligated to diagnose the issue. It is part of the Quality Of Implementation to diagnose as many things as possible. Note that in the general case it is potentially feasible to create a template definition that cannot be used to generate any valid instantiation but that is hard or even impossible to detect.

Comment: @David I understand that the program itself is ill-formed if no valid specialization can be generated from the template definition. That's why I said it's a good thing that all the compilers I tested it on fail to compile the code instead of allowing the ill-formed definition.