# Calling method with incomplete return type and my unexplainable template-workaround

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

I have to post quite a bit of code in order to explain my situation. The question, however, is simple (see also at the very bottom of my post, and the last code segment):

In `SubscriptProxy::is`, why does it compile when calling `this->get_element<Something>(parentElement);` but does not compile when calling `XYZ::get_element<Something>(parentElement);`?

---

File `Element.hpp`

```
class Element{};
```

File `HelperFunctions.hpp`:

```
#include "Element.hpp"

namespace XYZ {
    class Something;

    template<typename T>
    T get_element(Element* e) {
    }

    template<>
    Something get_element(Element* e);
}
```

File `HelperFunctions.cpp`:

```
#include "HelperFunctions.hpp"
#include "Something.hpp"

namespace XYZ {
    template<>
    Something get_element(Element* e) {
       // Convert Element to Something somehow
       return Something{};
    }
}
```

File `SubscriptProxy.hpp`:

```
#include "HelperFunctions.hpp"

namespace XYZ {
    class Something;

    template<typename C, typename D, typename E>
    class SubscriptProxy {
        C m_parent;
        E m_index; 

        template<typename T>
        T get_element(Element* e) const {
            return XYZ::get_element<T>(e); // call helper function
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool is(int index, Element*& e) const noexcept {
            Element* parentElement;
            if (!m_parent.template is<Something>(m_index, parentElement)) {
                return false;
            }
            auto d = this->get_element<Something>(parentElement);
            return d.template is<T>(index, e);
        }
    };
}
```

And then we have `Something.hpp` and `Something.cpp`, of course. It contains an operator which returns an instance of `SubscriptProxy`:

```
#include "SubscriptProxy.hpp"
#include "HelperFunctions.hpp"

namespace XYZ {
    class Something {
        SubscriptProxy<Something, Something, int> operator[] (int index) const noexcept;
    };
}
```

File `Something.cpp`:

```
#include "Something.hpp"

namespace XYZ {
SubscriptProxy<Something, Something, int> Something::operator[] (int index) const noexcept {
    return SubscriptProxy<Something, Something, int>{};
}
```

---

This compiles and works fine.

However, if I change the implementation of the `SubscriptProxy::is` method to the following:

```
        template<typename T>
        bool is(int index, Element*& e) const noexcept {
            Element* parentElement;
            if (!m_parent.template is<Something>(m_index, parentElement)) {
                return false;
            }
            auto d = XYZ::get_element<Something>(parentElement);
            return d.template is<T>(index, e);
        }
```

...it fails to compile with the error message: *Calling 'get_element' with incomplete return type 'Something'.*

Why?

Comment: full compilable example would be better. my guess is that you are using forward declaration, and not the class definition

Comment: @BЈовић I have amended the example. It should compile now.

Comment: No you didn't. See http://sscce.org/ - it doesn't have to compile, but it has to be complete.

Comment: Well... I did. Create 6 files, copy and paste the code into them => Short: As short as it can be since I wasn't sure where the problem is. I cannot put everything into 1 file since the nearly circular dependance is part of the problem; Self Contained: Everything is there; Correct: It compiles; Example: I am describing the problem, I try to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two-phase name lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) to check errors with template:

- one for any template argument, so compiler only check non dependant code.
- one at the instantiation (so all parameters are fixed).

`auto d = XYZ::get_element<Something>(parentElement);` is now longer template dependent, so compiler may provide error for this.

with `this->get_element`, it depends of `this` which is template.

Comment: I expect that someone who would ask the original question would fail to understand that correct answer.  In more beginner terms: The compiler expects to know the type returned by get_element earlier in the process of compilation when the call is not seen to be template dependent.  But if that call is not resolved until the template is instantiated, then the compiler delays needing to know the return type until that time (by which point the definition must have been seen).

Comment: Hmm, does that mean that I can't do anything to use `XYZ::get_element` directly but have to stick with `this->get_element`?

Comment: It means you can't use `XYZ::get_element<Something>` directly without `#include "something.h"` So it is your choice whether to include the class definition (rather than just forward declaration) vs. forcing the compiler to delay needing that definition.

Comment: I think, I can't do that because I need the complete type of `SubscriptProxy` in `Something`.

Comment: One way of dealing with that kind of nearly circular dependence is to split key hpp files into two parts.  When I do that, I move the declarations from xxx.hpp into xxx_declare.hpp, keeping the definitions in xxx.hpp (which includes xxx_declare.hpp) then have most cpp files that needed xxx still include xxx.hpp but most hpp include xxx_declare.  In your case the key is having SubscriptProxy defined in an hpp needed by Something but SubscriptProxy::is defined in a different hpp that needs Something.  Like you, I dislike the alternative of using that template kludge.  But it may be more common.

Comment: You need the definition of SubscriptProxy, including declaration of SubscriptProxy::is before the definition of Something, but you need the definition of SubscriptProxy::is after the definition of Something.