# Compiler not throwing error for constructor of class has syntax error

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following piece of code where i have genuinely made a syntax mistake:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type1,typename Type2>
class Pair{
public:
    Type1 first;
    Type2 second;
    Pair();
    Pair(Pair<Type1,Type2>& obj);
};

template<class Type1,class Type2>
Pair<Type1,Type2>::Pair(){
    first=Type1();
    second=Type2();
}

template<class Type1,class Type2>
Pair<Type1,Type2>::Pair(Pair<Type1,Type2>& obj1){
        cout<<"Inside the copy constructor\n";
        obj1.first=                                //THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC STMNT
}
int main()
{
/* Code here */
Pair<int,int> com1;
//Pair<complex1,complex2> com2(com1);
}
```

I dont find any compile/run time errors with this program. However if i uncomment the second line in main which calls the copy constructor then it throws a compiler time error. I know that class instatiates according to the types during runtime, but syntax errors like this for sure are checked in a templatized class during compilation stage. Why no compile time error then?
I am using VS2008.

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Maybe a non standard implementation of the two-phase lookup for templates?

Comment: @PaoloM Yes, it's Microsoft's very special "one-phase" version. Scheduled to be fixed some time soon, I believe.

Comment: This has a compiler error `'Type1' does not name a type` on line 3, please post code in question. Or perhaps you're not getting that syntax error because you're compiling *different* code

Comment: @paul Evans: fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a compiler bug. You can reproduce it in a much simpler way:

```
template <class T>
void f()
{
   = // should be an error, but is not in MSVC
}

int main()
{
}
```

This will create a diagnostic message like `error: expected primary-expression before '=' token` in non-MSVC compilers but compile happily in MSVC.

The apparent reason is that MSVC still has not implemented [two-phase lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) as required by the C++ standard. As MSVC developer Stephan T. Lavavej only recently explained in the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx):

> VC hasn't implemented three C++98/03 features: two-phase name lookup,
>   dynamic exception specifications, and export. Two-phase name lookup
>   remains unimplemented in 2015, but it's on the compiler team's list of
>   things to do, pending codebase modernization

Answer (score 2):

`Pair<complex1,complex2> com1;` use the default constructor while `Pair<complex1,complex2> com2(com1);` use the copy constructor.

Since without the second line the copy constructor is never used, it is not compiled; the compiler never generate code for it, therefore it never check if it can compile.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. For example, gcc returns a compilation error.

Comment: Seems fair. VS2012 compiles with no warnings.

Comment: @Lorenzo : it has nothing to do with whether i am calling it or not. I agree that 2nd phase compilation would not be done for copy constructor but copy constructor definition is atleast eligible for 1st phase compilation and basic error like syntax error for sure is caught as a part of compilation process irrespective of i am calling that func(copy constructor) or not