# Compiler differences on choosing the right overload for undefined function

Tags: c++, overloading

Let's have following code:

```
//template <typename ... A>
//void foo(char a, A ... args);

template <typename T> void P(T x) { std::cout << x << ' '; }

void foo(char a) { P(3); P(a); }

template <typename ... A>
void foo(int a, A ... args)
{
    foo(args...);
    P(a);
}

template <typename ... A>
void foo(char a, A ... args)
{
    P(a);
    foo(args...);
}

int main()
{
    foo('1', '2', 48, '4', '5');
}
```

It behaves differently on MSVC2015 and [ideone's GCC](http://ideone.com/6l4Xqr)

When `args...` equals `48, '4', '5'`, `foo` is called. Compilers differs on which `foo` is called. MSVC takes into account overloads defined bellow actual call (without declaration before) whereas GCC works only with already declared overloads. If I uncomment the declaration, both MSVC and GCC print `1 2 4 3 5 48`. If declaration is commented out, MSVC prints the same, but GCC prints `1 2 3 5 52 48` (52 is ascii for 4)

Which compiler is right according to the standard?

I have n4296 draft available, but I've failed to find an answer there, the document is kind of unreadable for me...

Comment: It's a well-known problem of MSVC. It doesn't implement two-phase lookup for templates. If you use regular functions rather than templates, there should be no difference.

Comment: @n.m.: Answers: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: Sorry which way? ↛ ↜ ↬ I'm lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC fails to implement [two phase name lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) for templates as prescribed by the standard. This compiler incorrectly defers all name resolution to the point of template *instantiation*.

Other compilers correctly resolve non-dependent names at the point of template *definition*. That's the reason for the difference you observe. At the point of definition, the second `foo` template is invisible so a conforming compiler cannot use it. But at the point of instantiation, it is visible and MSVC happily finds it.