# Declare function after template defined

Tags: c++, name-lookup

Let's say I have a template function:

```
template <class T>
void tfoo( T t )
{
    foo( t );
}
```

later I want to use it with a type, so I declare/define a function and try to call it:

```
void foo( int );

int main()
{
    tfoo(1);
}
```

and I am getting error from g++:

> ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
>        foo( t );

why it cannot find `void foo(int)` at the point of instantiation? It is declared at that point. Is there a way to make it work (without moving declaration of `foo` before template)?

Comment: isn't it because [the two phase lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed)?

Comment: @W.F. actually I would expect this to compile because of two phase lookup.

Comment: Perhaps declaring the function you want to call inside the function template will solve the problem for you?

Comment: Following my conversation with AnT and W.F. in the comments, what about a wrapper with a conversion operator that allows the use of ADL to call `foo`? Like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc92e572d02f601a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foo` in your case is a *dependent name*, since function choice depends on the type if the argument and the argument type depends on the template parameter. This means that `foo` is looked up in accordance with the rules of *dependent lookup*.

The difference between *dependent* and *non-dependent* lookup is that in case of dependent lookup *ADL-nominated namespaces* are seen as *extended*: they are extended with extra names visible from the point of template instantiation (`tfoo` call in your case). That includes the names, which appeared after the template declaration. The key point here is that *only* ADL-nominated namespaces are extended in this way.

(By *ADL-nominated namespace* I refer to namespace *associated with* function argument type and therefore brought into consideration by the rules of dependent name lookup. See "3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup")

In your case the argument has type `int`. `int` is a fundamental type. Fundamental types do not have associated namespaces (see "3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup"), which means that it does not nominate any namespace through ADL. In your example ADL is not involved at all. Dependent name lookup for `foo` in this case is no different from non-dependent lookup. It will not be able to see your `foo`, since it is declared *below* the template.

Note the difference with the following example

```
template <class T> void tfoo( T t )
{
    foo( t );
}

struct S {};

void foo(S s) {}

int main()
{
    S s;
    tfoo(s);
}
```

This code will compile since argument type `S` is a class type. It has an associated namespace - the global one - and it adds (nominates) that global namespace for dependent name lookup. Such ADL-nominated namespaces are seen by dependent lookup in their *updated* form (as seen from the point of the call). This is why the lookup can see `foo` and completes successfully.

---

It is a rather widespread misconception when people believe that the *second phase* of so called "two-phase lookup" should be able to see *everything* that was additionally declared below template definition all the way to the point of instantiation (point of the call in this case).

No, the second phase does not see everything. It can see the extra stuff *only in namespaces associated with function arguments*. All other namespaces do not get updated. They are seen as if observed from the point of template definition.

Comment: If I change the type of `T` to be some class, then shouldn't that class' namespace also come in? [it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19f9b4a7c8b9f0c0) So I'm clearly not understanding something. Only if `foo` accepts the dependent type does it seem to also be brought in.

Comment: @AndyG: It should. As i stated above, class types have *associated namespaces*. Fundamental types (like `int`) do not have associated namespaces. For this reason dependent lookup works differently for class types and fundamental types.

Comment: @AndyG You're calling `foo` with and `int` as an argument, there's no ADL going on.

Comment: If `S` is defined in a namespace does `foo` also will have to be defined in that namespace?

Comment: Thanks. My misunderstanding is a little embarrassing actually, but I'll share in case anybody that comes across this was similarly confused. The function `foo` as an unqualified name will be looked up according to its own arguments, and since `int` is a fundamental type, the list of candidates for ADL is empty. I mistakenly believed that the arguments to `tfoo` would also be used for ADL to find `foo`, so if `foo` was in the same namespace as `T`, then it should be brought in.

Comment: @AndyG: You are right. If `foo` was in the same namespace as actual `T`, then it should be brought in. This works for class types. This works for enum types. And so on (see 3.4.2). This *does not work* for fundamental types.

Comment: @AnT, then can you explain why the code I linked in my first comment does not compile?

Comment: @AndyG well it somehow compiles when your struct has conversion operator to int... [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/255b22bbe85e607a) Very nice explanation!

Comment: @AndyG: Well, I'd assume that the pedantic explanation goes as follows: associated namespaces that are involved into the lookup for a call to `foo` are determined by the argument types used in that call to `foo`. Since in this example `foo` is called with an argument `t.value` of type `int`, there are no associated namespaces. The fact that that `int` came there through `detail::adl_wrap` does not make any difference. It is still just an `int`.

Comment: Thanks again. So your previous comment was predicted on foo accepting T. I'm not totally crazy!

Comment: @W.F.: It is a critical distinction: ADL is defined by the *immediate argument type* used in the call, before any conversions. Obviously, the compiler cannot know that the argument will be converted to `int` before it actually finds `foo(int)` and decides that `foo(int)` is the best (only) candidate.

Comment: @W.F.: You previous comment (which you deleted for some reason) involved a function with a default argument. Default arguments (DA) cannot affect name lookup for the very same reason user-defined conversions (UDC) cannot affect name lookup. Both DA and UDC come into play during (or after) *overload resolution*. Overload resolution is only possible *after* name lookup is finished. For this reason DA and UDC cannot possibly affect name lookup. At name lookup stage, it is not yet known what DA and UDC are available.

Comment: @AnT I thought that the case was already covered by the fact `T` is fundamental type which wouldn't involve `foo` namespace and thought it didn't bring anything fresh to the conversation :)

Comment: The comment look more or less like: it still does not compile even after changing foo signature to `void foo(int, S ={})`