# About two phase lookup and this pointer

Tags: c++, templates

In c++ language, I learned about two phase lookup applied on template.
It said compiler checks twice at template.
But I can't understand the correlation between this pointer and two phase lookup.
So please tell me why removing this pointer (commented region) makes error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "f()\n";
    }
};

template <class T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    void g() {

        //this->f();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    b.g();
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? I tried 3 compilers, and they all work.

Comment: Works on compiler explorer. https://godbolt.org/z/3qeGQ5

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: do you mean you get an errror when you call `f();` instead of `this->f();` ? It is better to show the code that causes the error and the error. Showing code that needs some modification to get the error always causes confusion

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the **type** of `this`. It's a `B<T>*` in your example, which means it **depends** on `T`. Therefore the name lookup of `f` in `this->f` is done in the second phase, where it's known that `T==int` and thus `this` is a `B<int>*`.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
f();
```

`f` does not depend on a template parameter and thus looked up only in the template definition context.  With

```
this->f();
```

`f` does dependent on a template parameter (because `this` does as the parent class does)  and thus looked up in the template instanciation context.