# Trying to understand when a name is in the current instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I ran into this situation when trying to run down a subtle bug in some code.

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
   int f(){ return this->r; }
   int g(){ return r; }
};
```

The compiler flags an error on the definition of `S::g`, even when I never instantiate a specialization of the template, which is actually what I expected: The name r is unqualified and is not declared anywhere in scope.

What puzzles me is that an error is *not* flagged on the definition of `S::f` until I instantiate a specialization, say, `CT<int>f`, and call its `f`.

In other words, it seems like the compiler regards `this` as a pointer to a dependent type instead of a pointer to the current instantiation.

Is this correct? (My compiler is g++ 8.1.0). If g++ is doing the right thing, can you explain it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's normal. Since `this` does not have a type until T is defined, the evaluation of `this->` is deferred.

Comment: I normally expect a diagnostic when template code contains a construct that cannot possibly be well-formed no matter what types are substituted for the template type parameters. That seems to be the case here; what am I missing? How can ``this`` point to anything but the current instantiation? And the current instantiation has no member r.  Or is it simply that the standard doesn't require a diagnostic at this point and it's too tricky to check such cases?

Comment: [two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) might interest you.

Comment: @Kent Think like a compiler. if I see `a->b`, I will lookup the type of `a`, and see if that type has a member `b`. However, while **parsing** the template, `this` has no type to speak of. Sure, the compiler could have a special rule to handle that specific scenario, but there are soooo many more cases to consider here. What if `r` is of type `T`? wjhat if S inherits from `U<T>`? Is it really worth having an exceptional rule for that one specific scenario?

Comment: The only case I can think of where ``this`` would refer to a specialization of ``S<T>`` that has a member ``r`` is if a specialization of ``S<T>`` somehow retains the original definition of ``f()``. Otherwise, doesn't the specialization have to define its own ``f()``? I have a feeling I'm about to learn something subtle about C++ here ...

Comment: Incidentally, @Frank, "It's a special enough case to not be work diagnosing, even if we could" is an acceptable answer, if correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of template code.  You have dependent and non dependent code, that is code that depends on a template parameter and code that doesn't.  In

```
int g(){ return r; }
```

There is nothing that depends on `T` so the compiler checks out the code, see's it's not valid and you get an error.

In

```
int f(){ return this->r; }
```

`r` now depends on `T` because `this` depends on `T`.  Since you can't know if it is valid or not until you know what `T` is, the code is "ignored" and you only get an error once it's actually instantiated.

Comment: As I said, I understand the first case.  What puzzles me in the second is that ``this`` doesn't depend on T, not really; it refers to the current instantation, which we know has no member r no matter what T is.

Comment: @KentG.Budge I know, but answers aren't just for the original poster but also for others that come later.  I'm trying to cover all the bases in case they don't understand.

Comment: @KentG.Budge While true, the rules aren't that complex.  `this` can change depending on `T` (there could be specializations) so the name is dependent and lookup is deferred until the template is instantiated.