# Why is plain old function not selected for explicit call?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization

I have been reading the interesting topic [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) and somewhere encountered the following example.

```
struct Base{};

template<class T>
void f(T) { cout << "foo"; }

template<class T>
void functionSelector(T t)
{
    f(Base());
    f(t);
}

void f(Base) { cout << "bar"; }

int main ()
{
    functionSelector(Base());
    return 0;
}
```

This small program outputs

> foobar

and I definitely could not understand why it didn't output

> barbar

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The term you want to Google is` 2 phase lookup`

Comment: @JVApen That's perfect!! Thank you!

Comment: I guess [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed#comment9456869_7767726)  explains the situation

Comment: Move `void f(Base) { cout << "bar"; }` above `template functionSelector` to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: @crbah I'm glad it starts to make sense to you, I'm still searching for a good explanation to grasp it completely, especially if ADL comes into play