# What is the proper way to use static_assert in a non-instantiation template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

For example I got some template classes:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct A {
  void Print() {
    static_assert(false, "fall into unsupported Print function");
  }
};
// an instantiation if T is a unsigned type
template <typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>> {
  void Print() {
    std::cout << "A<int>" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

but due to the standard:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition,
> and that template is not instantiated, the template deﬁnition is
> ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

clang will immediately stop compiling and show failures, no matter if the template class gets instantiated or not, which is not what I meant to do.

I tried some other way like add a constexpr bool funtion to return false, but all failed.

So is there's any trick I can make the `static_assert` trigger only if the template class is instantiated?

Comment: The dupe is for `if constexpr` but the same answer applies for a template specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the expression inside `static_assert` depends on a template parameter, the assertion will be deferred until instantiation. You could, for example, define the following class template, `deferred_false`:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::false_type

template<typename>
struct deferred_false: std::false_type {};
```

Then, use it in the `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct A {
  void Print() {
    static_assert(deferred_false<T>::value, "fall into unsupported Print function");
  }
};
```

Comment: Although this works in practice, does it not violate the standard still?

Comment: @Dani Why? I would say this simply takes advantage of the [*Two-Phase Lookup*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7767626/8012646) for templates: *lookup for non-dependent names is done in the first phase, whereas lookup for names that depend on a template parameter is done in the second phase* ([in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed#comment9456869_7767726)).

Comment: @Dani No, it's fine, and the reason is because there *may* be a specialization of `deerred_false` which evaluates to `true_type`.