# link errors in XCode when defining a C++ class that inherits from a templated class

Tags: c++, xcode, class, templates, inherited

Here are the contents of the files. First the templated class :
in the .h file :

```
template <class T>
class templatedClass
{
    public :

    templatedClass(T val);
    ~templatedClass() {}

    void writeV();

    T v;
};
```

in the .cpp file :

```
template <class T>
templatedClass<T>::templatedClass(T val)
{
    v = val;
}

template <class T>
void templatedClass<T>::writeV()
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Everything is fine when build.

Now the inherited class :
in the .h file :

```
class inheritedClass : public templatedClass<float>
{
    public :

    inheritedClass(float val);
    ~inheritedClass() {}

    void write();
};
```

in the .cpp file :

```
inheritedClass::inheritedClass(float val)
: templatedClass<float>(val)
{

}

void inheritedClass::write()
{
    writeV();
}
```

When building I received the following link errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "templatedClass<float>::writeV()", referenced from:
      inheritedClass::write() in inheritedClass.o
  "templatedClass<float>::templatedClass(float)", referenced from:
      inheritedClass::inheritedClass(float) in inheritedClass.o
```

What is wrong with my code? Have I to use special building options in XCode to succeed?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing template class instantiation problem. To solve it, you should put your template implementation code in the header file. By which I mean, this part:

```
template <class T>
templatedClass<T>::templatedClass(T val)
{
    v = val;
}

template <class T>
void templatedClass<T>::writeV()
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

There are other options, such as keeping a separate template implementation file and including it in the other cpp file, or instantiating the class template somewhere else altogether...

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) or [class template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210914/class-template-instantiation) for more details.