# C++ - issue while porting C++ code from Visual Studio to Linux Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, visual-studio

I have a project build in Microsoft Visual Studio and I want to port it in Linux(OpenSuse 12.2) using Eclipse IDE.

The project is using OpenCV and I have managed to build OpenCV in Linux. It is not that huge, it contains 3 .cpp files and 4 .h files which actually defines the classes used in the project and one of the .cpp files contains the `main()` function.

However, there is one additional `instances.inc` file with the following content:

```
#include "graph.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable: 4661)
#endif

// Instantiations: <captype, tcaptype, flowtype>
// IMPORTANT:
//    flowtype should be 'larger' than tcaptype
//    tcaptype should be 'larger' than captype

template class Graph<int,int,int>;
template class Graph<short,int,int>;
template class Graph<float,float,float>;
template class Graph<double,double,double>;
```

where `graph.h` which contains the declaration of `Graph` class.

I changed the extension of the `instances.inc` file to `instances.h` file. However, when I try to build the project I receive the following error:

```
../src/BranchAndMincut.cpp:246: undefined reference to `Graph<int, int, int>::maxflow(bool, Block<int>*)'
```

which I guess that it is related to the `.inc` file. Do you know how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I also want to mention that `instanes.inc` files was included at the end of the `graph.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using instantiating of the template classes. First thing is you may delete .cpp-file which contains realization of this template class `Graph` and put implementation of the methods and etc in the `Graph.h` file - this action will make instantiating unnecessary.
Next thing you can try to do is rename instances.h/inc to instances.cpp and compile it (place it in makefile or what do you use).

I've found a good links:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14272/

[class template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210914/class-template-instantiation)

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: After this step the content of the `includes.inc` will be unnecessary?  Can I remove the instantiates of the `Graph` class?

Comment: After placing all the implementation part in the header file - yes, you will not need instantiating after this.