# template class of static const member variable vs static const member variable initialization

Tags: c++, templates

below code compiled fine

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    static const T value = 1 + foo::value;
};
```

but this one is error

```
struct foo
{
    static const int value = 1 + foo::value;
};
```

and also

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
     static const int value = 1 + foo::value;
};

Error   1   error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier    c:\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp  13  1   ConsoleApplication2
```

i think second case is reasonable anyway

but first one is how it works?

can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example there is no static member variable `foo::value`, there exists only a *template* for such a variable, it doesn't exist until you actually try to use it. So if you do e.g. `foo<int>::value` then you will get an error for the first one as well.

Comment: I would add that if OP really call `foo<int>::value` he would get different compilation error as compiler will try to resolve recursive template call of the static field...

Answer (score 0):

You should look [Template Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210914/class-template-instantiation).
Template Instantiation is done when try to make an object of that class.
First time you compile the program then type of static member `value` depends on the template argument you pass while instantiating it. In the second case, `foo` is compiled completely and compiler finds out that value is not declared so reports the error.