# CRTP Member Visibility

Tags: c++, polymorphism, visibility, crtp

I am trying to better understand C++ class member visibility as it pertains to the CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern). I should note that I understand the use of CRTP and its "compile time polymorphism".

I have the following snippet of code.

```
// A C++ constraint for a type that is "closable".
template <typename T>
concept IsClosable = requires(T t)
{
  { t.closeImplementation() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

// I defer the constraint "IsClosable" to the function rather than the class
// otherwise when I use CRTP, the constraint would fail. 
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  template <IsClosable C = T>
  void close()
  {
    static_cast<C*>(this)->closeImplementation();
  }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
// Visibility in question here.
public:
  void closeImplementation()
  {

  }
};
```

I have attempted to trace what the compiler is actually seeing here. For simplicity I will remove the constraint. Doing so I have the following

1. Restating the base code

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  void close()
  {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->closeImplementation();
  }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
// Visibility in question here.
public:
  void closeImplementation()
  {

  }
};
```

2. The compiler first ignores the template declaration as nothing instantiates it yet.
3. The compiler then comes across this line and starts to instantiate a template. Note that even though the full `Derived` class is not declared, this should be sufficient for template substitution.

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
```

leading to the following

```
template <>
class Base<Derived>
{
public:
  void close()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->closeImplementation();
  }
};
```

I am not fully sure if this line makes sense just yet until we have the inheritance. It seems like before the inheritance takes place we are casting `this` which is a `Base<Derived>` base object to `Derived` which doesn't seem compatible.

4. After the template is instantiated we then continue the declaration of the

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
// Visibility in question here.
public:
  void closeImplementation()
  {

  }
};
```

And if we substitute the methods we get from `Base<Derived>` this should more or less look like

```
class Derived // Inheriting from Base<Derived>
{
public:
  void closeImplementation()
  {

  }

  void close()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->closeImplementation();
  }
};
```

So from this I have a few questions.

1. Why can `closeImplementation` not be private if it "looks" like "close" can still access it?
2. Does the line `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->closeImplementation()` get invoked in the `Base<Derived>` class or `Derived`? If it is the former, how does that work?
3. Is my understanding of how the compiler views this code correct?

Comment: When I do CRTP, in my `Derived` I do `friend Base<Derived>;`.

Comment: Agree with @Elijay. Because this is "implementation", it should not be public. But you should make it possible to access by the Base. So "friend" fits very well here.

Comment: *"Does the line `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->closeImplementation()` get invoked in the `Base<Derived>` class or `Derived`?"* -- The line is inside `Base<T>::close()`. Why would it be invoked anywhere else? *(Don't let yourself be confused by "more or less look like". You can rearrange code to get a better handle on the semantics of a class, but not to understand the syntax.)*

Comment: *"I am not fully sure if this line makes sense just yet until we have the inheritance."* -- Your reasoning looks good (but imprecise about what is instantiated) up to this point. See [class template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8210914) -- instantiating the class does not imply instantiating the member functions. *Is that close enough to be a duplicate?*

Comment: @JaMiT
That is correct that it is inside `Base<T>::close` but the surrounding closure is not exactly clear to me. Is it executing in the context of the `Base` class or the `Derived` class? What type is `this` here? Does it depend on it's closure?

Comment: @nick2225 *"but the surrounding closure is not exactly clear to me"* -- There is no surrounding closure. That is a concept related to lambdas. -- *"Is it executing in the context of the Base class or the Derived class?"*--There is no "context" for execution here (that would mean something like a thread). Nor do I think this is what you mean. You probably mean a compile-time concept, not a runtime concept, something like *"Which class is this code part of?"* (which can be easily answered by looking at where the function is defined). *Don't let yourself be confused by your re-write of the code.*

Comment: @nick2225 *"What type is `this` here?"* -- For any class `X`, when inside a (non-static) member function of `X` that is declared as part of `X` (not one simply inherited from a base class), the type of `this` is `X*` (possibly with `const`/`volatile`). Nothing in this question changes that basic concept. Inside `Base<T>::close()`, the type of `this` is `Base<T>*`. Hence, there is a need to cast to `T*`.

Comment: @JaMiT
You are right that for a given class `Base<Derived>` that the `this` object refers to `Base<Derived>*`. However, the context I was missing is described in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758834/8929431.

For inheritance the `this` object points to both `Base<Derived>*` and `Derived*`. This is the piece I was missing. `Base<Derived>*` on its own can not downcast to `Derived*` without the inheritance line `class Derived : public Base<Derived>`.

Comment: The idioms used in CRTP are bit counter intuitive to me, as I am usually familiar with the inverse. Typically I have normal runtime polymorphism with a `Derived*` pointer which also points to a `Base*` pointer. It was just odd seeing Base class syntax be aware of its Derived class, but I guess that is how compile time polymorphism works.