# When are class templates instantiated?

Tags: c++

Suppose you have the following (ill-formed) program:

```
struct A
{
    A(int, int)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    B()
    {
        if (sizeof (T) == 1)
        {
            throw A(0); // wrong, A() needs two arguments
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

GCC compiles this program without any errors, clang++ refuses it with an error.

1. Is it justified to say thats it is *not* a bug in GCC because the template isnt instantiated?
2. What magic does clang do to find this error?
3. What does the C++ standard say about those situations?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182359/template-instantiation-details-of-gcc-and-ms-compilers/ . The two keywords are "point of instantiation", "two phase lookup" and "(non)dependent names". Wait, those were three keywords.

Comment: Oh crap, I want to revoke my close-vote but can't. That was stupid from my side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The template is instantiated when used. However, it should be compiled when it's defined. Your code `A(0)` uses the name `A`, which doesn't depend on the template parameter `T`, so it should be resolved when the template is defined. This is called two-phase lookup. The way clang finds the error is simply by trying to resolve the call `A(0)` as soon as it sees it.

My version of GCC also compiles this code silently, even with `-pedantic-errors`. Both C++03 and C++11 say that no diagnostic is required, even though the program is ill-formed, so GCC conforms. This is 14.6/7 in C++03 and 14.6/8 in C++11:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition,
>   and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is
>   ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Ah, I see. When I change A to a template class and adjust the call to `A<T>(0)` clang compiles it. Thanks also for the hint to two-phase lookup. Do you have some interesting pointers?

Comment: It's ill-formed but with an explicit mention that no diagnostics are required.

Comment: @AProgrammer: yes, updated. I didn't realise C++11 had added that mention.

Comment: @Steve, It was already the case in C++03 (14.6/7), and if I'm not misinterpreting the change marks, in C++98. (There is additional language in C++03 making it "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" to have an incomplete type complete at instantiation point.).

Comment: @AProgrammer: oops, I was looking at the wrong paragraph in C++03, they were renumbered.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes. When no valid specialization exist but the template isn't instantiated -- like here -- the program is ill-formed, but no diagnostic is required (14.6/8).  So both clang and g++ are right.
2. clang does more checks than g++ on the template declaration.
3. See above.

Comment: How does the behaviour differ when we use an undeclared/undefined name instead of `A`? GCC complains (unless we specify `-fpermissive`) when the name is undeclared (but not when it’s undefined) but is this covered by the standard or is this still a case that doesn’t *require* diagnostic?

Comment: @Konrad: the text is "If no
valid specialization can be generated for a template deﬁnition, and that template is not instantiated, the
template deﬁnition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.". In this case, modified so that the code contains a used of an entirely undefined name, no specialization of `B` can be generated.