# a template ref class isn't seen in a client project

Tags: templates, c++-cli

I have a template class :

```
namespace MyApp
{
namespace Interop
{

    template < class A, class B>
    public ref class MyClass
    {
        public:
            MyClass(){}
            ~MyClass(){}

    };

}
}
```

---

In a client project this class isn't visible:

```
class A;
class B;
using namespace MyApp::Interop;

void func()
{
    MyClass< A,B >^ h;
}
```

I get error C2065: 'MyClass' : undeclared identifier.
If MyClass isn't template it is visible in this context.

Comment: This isn't plain C++. Please retag it with the appropriate language (C++-CLI or C++/CX, whichever it is).

Comment: What on earth is is the semicolon doing in `namespace Interop {;` ?? Is this some sort of ancient viking C++?

Comment: Adosi you're funny, let's jump over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C++ Templates

Class templates have the usual semantics of C++ templates (in other words, you can't you expect CLR clients to "magically" know about and instantiate C++ templates that aren't even available in Assembly Metadata (i.e. Reflection Info)).

The classical C++ solution is going to be *explicit instantiation* of all the template arguments that you are going to expect this to be used with.

I'll defer to the standard faq items for C++:

- [Template instantiation details of GCC and MS compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182359/template-instantiation-details-of-gcc-and-ms-compilers)
- [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056) (On explicit instantiation)

### CLR Generic Types

In case you wanted a generic CLR type (with CLR semantics, that is) use `generic` instead of `template`: **[Generic Classes (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef48fy.aspx)**. Example:

```
// generics_instance_fields1.cpp
// compile with: /clr
// Instance fields on generic classes
using namespace System;

generic <typename ItemType>
ref class MyClass {
// Field of the type ItemType:
public :
   ItemType field1;
   // Constructor using a parameter of the type ItemType:
   MyClass(ItemType p) {
     field1 = p; 
   }
};

int main() {
   // Instantiate an instance with an integer field:
   MyClass<int>^ myObj1 = gcnew MyClass<int>(123);
   Console::WriteLine("Integer field = {0}", myObj1->field1);

   // Instantiate an instance with a double field:
   MyClass<double>^ myObj2 = gcnew MyClass<double>(1.23);
   Console::WriteLine("Double field = {0}", myObj2->field1);

   // Instantiate an instance with a String field:
   MyClass<String^>^ myObj3 = gcnew MyClass<String^>("ABC");
   Console::WriteLine("String field = {0}", myObj3->field1);
}
```