# C++ exception specifications being deprecated in C++11

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Why are the `exception specifications` being deprecated post-release of the C++11 standard?

It officially mentions the reason is because of introduction of `noexcept`

I do not fully understand this but is it due to performance issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2665194/2183287 and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114338/why-are-exception-specifications-bad

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec: *noexcept is an improved version of throw(), which is deprecated in C++11. Unlike throw(), noexcept will not call std::unexpected and may or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to implement noexcept without the runtime overhead of throw().*